# Advantage of using WMS over WFS

Tags: openlayers-2, wms, wfs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Comparison of WMS and WFS services](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8348/comparison-of-wms-and-wfs-services)

I am trying to overlay WFS over WMS and still [not successful](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25446/unable-to-create-wfs-successfully/25509#25509). So wanted to know when and why would someone use WFS?

I need to extract the info from the WFS layer that I am trying to overlay onto the WMS. If yes how?

Comment: There is an existing comparison of WMS and WFS at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8348/comparison-of-wms-and-wfs-services

Comment: oh did not see that, please close this question

Comment: I changed my comment to an Answer which should let you close it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an existing comparison of WMS and WFS available in [Stack Exchange GIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8348/comparison-of-wms-and-wfs-services) already.